# Difference between dir(string) and dir(someString) in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just start learning programming with python. As I learn if I want to list all string modules I wrote:

```
import string
print dir(string)
```

Result:

> ['Formatter', 'Template', '_TemplateMetaclass', '**builtins**',
>   '**doc**', '**file**', '**name**', '**package**', '_float', '_idmap',
>   '_idmapL', '_int', '_long', '_multimap', '_re', 'ascii_letters',
>   'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'atof', 'atof_error', 'atoi',
>   'atoi_error', 'atol', 'atol_error', 'capitalize', 'capwords',
>   'center', 'count', 'digits', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'hexdigits',
>   'index', 'index_error', 'join', 'joinfields', 'letters', 'ljust',
>   'lower', 'lowercase', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'octdigits', 'printable',
>   'punctuation', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rsplit',
>   'rstrip', 'split', 'splitfields', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'translate',
>   'upper', 'uppercase', 'whitespace', 'zfill']

But what's about this:

```
someString = "someValues"
print dir(someString)
```

Result:

> ['**add**', '**class**', '**contains**', '**delattr**', '**doc**',
>   '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getitem**',
>   '**getnewargs**', '**getslice**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**',
>   '**le**', '**len**', '**lt**', '**mod**', '**mul**', '**ne**',
>   '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**rmod**',
>   '**rmul**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**',
>   '**subclasshook**', '_formatter_field_name_split',
>   '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode',
>   'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index',
>   'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle',
>   'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace',
>   'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split',
>   'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate',
>   'upper', 'zfill']

Why the result is different?

Comment: Because `someString` is an instance of `str` and `string` is a module from standard library.

Comment: Indeed, the `dir()` of two totally different things is likely to be different.

Comment: RTFM (Read the Fine Manual):  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir "*The default dir() mechanism behaves differently with different types of objects*".  There follows a list of items displayed depending on type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a Python console:

```
>>> import string
>>> type(string)
<type 'module'>

>>> type("someValues")
<type 'str'>

>>> help(dir)
```

> dir([object]) -> list of strings
>
> If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.
>   Else, return an alphabetized list of names comprising (some of) the >attributes
>   of the given object, and of attributes reachable from it.
>   If the object supplies a method named **dir**, it will be used; otherwise
>   the default dir() logic is used and returns:
>
> ```
> for a module object: the module's attributes.
> for a class object:  its attributes, and recursively the attributes
>   of its bases.
> for any other object: its attributes, its class's attributes, and
>   recursively the attributes of its class's base classes.
> ```

Thus, `dir(string)` returns the attributes of the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module while
`dir("someValues")` returns the attributes of the [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) class as well as the attributes of instances thereof. For a proper distinction, take a look at [Modules, Classes, and Objects](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html).